# Can a table with only Foreign key be normalized?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am surprised to see that there is no information on the net about this question...
Let's say I have two tables, A and B.
A has a primary key which act as a foreign key in table B.
B does not have its own primary key but only foreign key.
So in case of normalization, what about table B?
I mean should we leave it be or normalize it by making our own primary key in table b required that there is need of normalization in table B.

Comment: There are few exceptions: every table should have a primary key.

Comment: Appreciate it. But for normalization, a table must have a primary key? Right @MitchWheat

Comment: No. Can be in 3NF without the referencing table having a primary key. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form  section "A design that also complies with higher normal forms"

Comment: Database Normalization is part of relational database theory. Under the relational model the relation is the only data structure and every relation always has at least one candidate key. Normalization is concerned with candidate keys and superkeys, not primary keys.

Comment: Why do you think your B doesn't have a primary key (candidate key)? Do you mean it has duplicate rows? Normalization has nothing to do with foreign keys.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> **TLDR**: You don't need Table B if it only has 1 column

If you have `tableA`

```
id_x  | x
1       a
2       c
3       b
```

and `tableB`

```
id_x references tableA.id_x
```

The normalisation will depend on the usages of id_x in tableB.

If you will have id_x multiple times, you could for example add a field in tableA with a int.

So, `tableA`

```
id_x   | x | number_of_times_id_x_would_appear_in_table_b
1        a   10
2        c   0
3        b   19
```

If it wouldn't appear in tableB multiple times, it should be a boolean then

```
id_x   | x | would_id_x_appear_in_table_b
1        a   true
2        c   false
3        b   true
```